# Handlebars adding forwardslash "/" to the page address for some, and not for others

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have 10 `.handlebars` that are called with the following express GET methods:

```js
app.get('/pagename1', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('page1');
});

app.get('/pagename2', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('page2');
});

app.get('/pagename3', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('page3');
});
........
```

I am not sure why, but when the webpage is loaded, the handlebars automatically add a `/` to the browser address for some of the handlebars, which breaks the image links on the page. While others it does not.

I checked all the routing to ensure that the pages that have these issues do not a `/` in their express `app.get()` methods.

Any ideas to why this happens?

Comment: /: That’s not a backslash, this is a backslash: \

Comment: oops typo. thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

Sound like that the / is added at the client side.
What is the framework that you are working inside page1-3? what is rendered there?